# projectile motion (dynamic) stone

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, projective-module

---

2) A stone is projected downwards with a velocity of 20m/s at an angle of 30degrees below a horizontal line through the point of projection. Find the velocity of the stone after 2 sec.

t=0 => v=20cos30**i**-20sin30**j**

**V**=20cos30**i**+(-20sin30-9.8t)**j**
**r**=20cos30t+(-20sin30t-4.9t^2)**j**

t=2sec
**v**=20cos30**i**+[-20sin30-9.8(2)]**j**
=17.32**i**-29.6**j**

square root of 17.32^2+29.6^2 = 34.29

Comment: Without proper typesetting and plugging only numerical values, this solution is horrible.

Comment: Third displayed line (about $r$) is not needed.  The line below $t=2$ sec is the approximate answer. The square root line should be deleted, that's the speed, which you were not asked to find, grader might think you are confused and think velocity and speed are the same thing.

Comment: Given the nature of the work the OP put forth in the problem statement, I think this question is asking "How do I format & typeset and arrange my work to be the most meaningful and accurate?".  Since the OP did not actually ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal speed:
$$V\cos\theta$$
Vertical speed (positive downward):
$$V\sin\theta+gt$$
Oblique speed:
$$\sqrt{(V\cos\theta)^2+(V\sin\theta+gt)^2}=\sqrt{(20\cos30°)^2+(20\sin 30°+9.81\times2)^2}\approx34.31 m/s$$

Comment: I saw your fix and deleted my comment.